# biblatex with verbose-trad2: how not to print page range of article if a page number is set?

Tags: biblatex

When `\cite`ing an article which has a `pages` defined in the bibtex source, and if passing a page argument, biblatex display both.

Example: `\cite[42]{Key}` will result in something like:

> Author, "Title", *Journal*, etc., **p.31-52, p.42**.

If I'm not passing any page number (42), it's fine to have the page range (31-52). But if I am, I'd rather not, and have only:

> Author, "Title", *Journal*, etc., p.42.

Can this be done ?

Comment: did you try the `citepages=omit` package option?

Comment: Mhh.. I missed that one. Thanks, it does work!

Comment: I made it into an answer so this can be closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the `citepages=omit` option.